# csharp generic repository: could not use Select() method with IEnumerable (error: explicit cast needed)

Tags: c#, linq, generics, entity-framework-6, ienumerable

It's been 6 months that I use Csharp and mariaDb. After working only with POC I started to be interrested on generic repository, EF6 and functionnal programming. I'm actually doing some refactory for my applications.

In my generic repository I have this code:

```
public IEnumerable<TType> FindColumn<TType>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> selection, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> OrderExpression)
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).OrderBy(OrderExpression).Select(selection).ToList();
        }
```

I operate this code like this in the non-generic repository:

```
public IEnumerable<chantiers> GetAllChantiersAsc()
        {
            return FindColumn(d => d.NomChantier, d => d.NomClient.Equals(clients.NomClient), d=>d.NomChantier);
        }
```

I have this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 
>       'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.chantiers>'.
>        An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In my application I want to have a generic method for retrieving a column from my EF6 Entity.
 Thank you for your help.

Comment: `d=>d.NomChantier` - that looks like you're selecting the name which is a string, but your method expects to return a list of `chantiers`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot to add TEntity to the function identifier of FindColumn:

```
public IEnumerable<TType> FindColumn<TEntity, TType>(...)
```

And of course you already tried to find out which of your parameters is incorrect by fully specifying all types:

```
public IEnumerable<Chantiers> GetAllChantiersAsc()
{
    Expression<Func<myEntityType, Chantiers>> selection = d => d.NomChantier;
    Expression<Func<myEntityType, bool>> predicate = d => d.NomClient.Equals(clients.NomClient);
    Expression<Func<myEntityType, Chantiers>> orderExpression = d=>d.NomChantier;
    IEnumerable<Chantiers> result = FindColumn<myEntityType, Chantiers>(
         selection,
         predicate,
         orderExpression);
     return result;
}
```

I'm sure your compiler will tell you which of your parameters has the incorrect type. My guess is that `nomChantiers` is your problem, as it seems to be a Name, not a `Chantiers`